# Paypal payment with credit card and debit card

Tags: android, paypal

I want to integrate paypal payment functionality in my android application .

how to do payment to paypal through debit and credit card ?

If it is not possible ? Can you suggest me another option using payment through Debit and Credit Card ?

Comment: there is an paypal SDK for android check it https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf

Comment: I think [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564482/how-to-implement-credit-card-payment-in-android-application) should help You regarding this. It describe about the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Mobile Express Checkout Library: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECOnMobileDevices

User will have 2 choices: Paypal account or Credit card.
You can download demo by:

- go to here https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index
- "Mobile Libraries" tab
- "Mobile Express Checkout Library" - download zip file which contents library, document and demo.
- Run demo you will have screen with "Pay with a card" option.

Goodluck.

Comment: TheSpring , please do a favor by publishing your solution .